# Hibernate connecting table unique on columns problem

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have problem with hibernate because he creates connecting table (I don't know why will be nice if can tell me where and why), and what is worst he using unique on columns and i cant add more then one user with the same role.

Whole project: https://github.com/dextep/sms/tree/master/src/main/java/pl/popiel/sms

[Database look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZBwI.png)

User.class

```
package pl.popiel.sms.model.user;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.UniqueElements;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="sms_users")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sms_users_seq", sequenceName = "sms_users_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sms_users_seq")
    private long id;

    @Email
    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="mobile_nr")
    private String mobileNumber;


    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName != null ? firstName.concat(" ").concat(lastName) : "";
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role.class

```
package pl.popiel.sms.model.user;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.UniqueElements;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="sms_roles")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sms_roles_seq", sequenceName = "sms_roles_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sms_roles_seq")
    private long id;

    private String role;

    public Role() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that I miss the @ManyToMany annotation at 'roles' in User class.

Solve:

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<Role> roles;
```